# R Lubridate is ordering months and weekdays alphabetically by default

Tags: r, data-analysis, lubridate

I'm using Lubridate in R Studio and when I use group by (with dplyr) to group by months or weekdays it sorts it automatically in alphabetical order. How can I change this to date order?

Here is the code:

```
df %>% group_by(months(DateColumn)) %>% summarise(Freq=n())
```

DateColumn has te following structure:

[image]

When I view the result this is the order. (Same for plots)

[image]

Comment: The function "months" is a base R built-in, this quation isn't actually using any lubridate functions.

Answer (score 1):

After the `summarise` step, we can `arrange` the rows by `match`ing with the inbuilt `month.name` (months in the correct order), and then convert the 'Months' to a `factor` with `levels` specified (so that it can be used later in `ggplot` to order in the same order as the `levels`)

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_by(Months = months(DateColumn)) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  arrange(match(month.name, Months)) %>%
  mutate(Months = factor(Months, levels = Months))
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(DateColumn = seq(as.POSIXct("2015-05-10"), 
     length.out = 30, by = '1 month'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using data from @akrun's answer. Here is an alternative:

```
 df <- data.frame(DateColumn = seq(as.POSIXct("2015-05-10"), 
                                  length.out = 30, by = '1 month'))
df %>% 
  mutate(Date=month(DateColumn,label=T),ID=row_number()) %>%
  group_by(Date) %>% 
  arrange(Date) %>% 
  select(-DateColumn)
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using lubridate here at all. If you were, then it would work as you wanted. `months` is a base R function. The function you want is `month`, with `label=TRUE`.

```
df |> group_by(month(DateColumn,label=TRUE)) |> summarise(Freq=n())
```

Which gives the below output (I don't have your exact data, so I used my own):

```
  `month(timestamp, label = TRUE)`  Freq
  <ord>                            <int>
1 Jan                                 10
2 Mar                                 25
3 Apr                                  6
4 Aug                                 15
5 Sep                                 12
6 Oct                                 10
7 Nov                                  9
```

Comment: You can set `abbr=FALSE` if you want full month names too.